# Run one query multiple times with low limit or a single time with a large limit, server load differance?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the option to do the following, run one query 1000 times with a limit of 1, or the same query with a limit of 1000 once.

Is there a significant performance difference in the two?

Some context:
The results of a query is used for a larger XML operation that can take up to a few seconds to complete, so what I am currently doing is using a Javascript loop with AJAX to get one element at a time and display them as the query goes along and finishes its work, giving the appearance of a faster website then what it really is.
If I did one large query it could take a minute before the page loads at all (if not using javascript but just pure PHP)

I am just wanting to see if the "faster" page is worth the potential extra server load or if its better to just have users wait for a while (something that I would feel bad about)

Comment: Erm... a minute for one query with LIMIT 1000, yet microseconds for the same query with LIMIT 1?

Comment: The answer is probably going to be somewhere in between. It might be possible to do it all in one request as well with intermittent flushes to update the page

Comment: @raina77ow that is with the added XML operations. (A live RRS feed) It collects loads of data from it and can take a while for the page to display if 1000 of them have to be retrieved at once.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you give a brief overview of the table(s)' structure? It might be beneficial to store the results of the single query in some intermediate `in-memory` layer, then process these step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some Ux research could benefit you in making this decision. There's some great articles out there where folks have studied how page performance impacts their site or app. How these studies apply to you will depend on the nature of your experience.

Upon a quick search, I found a few that stood out. Good luck making the best informed decision for you.

- http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2011/11/23/case-study-slow-page-load-mobile-business-metrics/
- http://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/
- http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/21/recommendations-mobile-commerce-websites/

Comment: Good reads all of these, a page load time on my site incredibly fast (0.0028 seconds) when loading things with javascript when its ready (the page is loaded, but the content comes in on the fly)

When loading everything at once it can take 10-20 seconds depending on the external XML.

I am guessing being able to display content more or less instantly to give users something to focus on while more is loaded is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The other approach you could consider - Caching on the web server.

I do not know if this is possible in PHP, but we can do this in .Net. You can cache the data in your web server for an x amount of time. You can then serve the cached data while you are waiting from your refresh from the database - this refresh can be executed in a timer based callback function. This way you will always have the latest large dataset from x minutes ago.

Hope this helps.